# Обновить кэш на стороне клиента

Tags: веб-программирование, javascript, html, php

Есть страница, на ней картинка. Пользователь зашел, посмотрел, ушел.
Картинку на сервере поменяли. 
Пользователь вернулся, но картинка не поменялась, пока он не обновил страницу или вовсе не очистил кэш.
Как этого избежать?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: так как клиенты вправе кешировать, то часто применяют следующий метод - к адресу картинки добавляют случайный хвост (можно метку времени).

Comment: Есть хорошая статья http://javascript.ru/optimize/cache-versioning

Comment: Как уже сказал KoVadim, примерно так: `<img src="/img/my_photo.png?v=30122014" />` но обычно актуально только для css и js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Настроить заголовки отвеат на стороне сервера, отвечающие за кэширование. Например:

   Cache-Control:max-age=86400
   Cache-Control:public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
   ETag:"55643266-47ff"
   Expires:Mon, 01 Jun 2015 12:25:09 GMT
   Last-Modified:Tue, 26 May 2015 08:44:22 GMT
   Pragma:public

В данном примере сервер сообщает браузеру: "эта картинка имеет срок жизни 24 часа (86400 секунд) и оно истечёт (Expires) 1 июня в 12:25:09, может быть закэширована любым публичным прокси-сервером (Cache-Control:public), но должна быть перепроверена как на сервере (must-revalidate), так и на прокси (proxy-revalidate), дата последнего изменения (Last-Modified) 26 мая 08:44:22"

Вы можете сделать несколько папок на сервере для картинок в зависимости от того, как часто они обновляются, и для каждой картинки в соответствующей папке возвращать те или иные значения заголовков кэширования. Вплоть до "no-caсhe", хотя это и не рекомендуется.

2. При загрузке новой картинки присваивать ей новое уникальное имя. Тогда браузер гарантированно загрузит новую картинку

Использование суффикса для картинки, как предлагают в комментариях, на мой взгляд, нецелесообразно, так как проще поменять имя самой картинки.